# C++ Compilation error: Undefined identifier (for a function parameter)

Tags: c++, reference, compiler-errors, function-parameter

I have a C++ class main.cpp in which I created a class like following:

```
class MapSearchNode
{
 public:
unsigned int x;  // the (x,y) positions of the node
unsigned int y; 

MapSearchNode() { x = y = 0; }
MapSearchNode( unsigned int px, unsigned int py ) { x=px; y=py; }

float goalDistance( MapSearchNode &nodeGoal );

};
float MapSearchNode::goalDistance( MapSearchNode &nodeGoal )
{
float xd = fabs(float(((float)x - (float)nodeGoal.x)));
float yd = fabs(float(((float)y - (float)nodeGoal.y)));

return xd + yd;
}

int main{
    //treatment
}
```

And it works fine but then I wanted to seperate the class MyClass, so I created a MyClass.h and MyClass.cpp and seperated the code like following:

MyClass.h

```
#ifndef _MAPSEARCHNODE_H
#define _MAPSEARCHNODE_H


class MapSearchNode
{
public:
    MapSearchNode();
MapSearchNode( unsigned int px, unsigned int py );

public:
unsigned int x;  
unsigned int y; 
    float goalDistance( MapSearchNode &goalNode );

};
#endif
```

MyClass.cpp

```
#include "MapSearchNode.h"

MapSearchNode::MapSearchNode():x(0), y(0))
{}
MapSearchNode::MapSearchNode( unsigned int px, unsigned int py ):x(px), y(py) 
{}

float MapSearchNode::goalDistance(MapSearchNode &goalNode ){
float xDistance = fabs(float(((float)x - (float)goalNode.x)));
float yDistance = fabs(float(((float)y - (float)goalNode.y)));

return xDistance + yDistance;
}
```

Bur when i try to compile i have an error:

```
Undefined identifier goalNode; 
 //for the function goalDistance
```

Can someone please explain me why am I getting this error and how to fix it.

EDIT: I hope I haven't forgotten anything now.

EDIT:
Well thanks a lot to those who downrated. Some of us are not experts like you and it's hard for them to see errors even small ones!

Comment: float MyClass::Calculate( MyCass &myClass ) -

MyCass should be MyClass?

Comment: You're missing a `;` at the end if `class MyClass { ... }; <- this one here is crucial`

Comment: The spelling mistake is in both versions of the code, including the original "working" version, so it's obviously just a typo. Did you include the header in `MyClass.cpp`?

Comment: @Mat I forgot to add it in the question.

Comment: @Anila: please post real code. Debugging a compile error on something you're continuously changing is impossible.

Comment: @Mat Ok I just thought it'll be easier to see the problem like this because the real code is quite long.

Comment: What you should be doing is extracting the shortest possible piece of code that reproduces your problem, and posting that _exactly_.

Comment: @Mat ok I'll edit my question.

Comment: @Anila Are you including `MyClass.h` in `MyClass.cpp`?

Comment: @Mat I've added the real code.

Comment: @Anila: the updated code compiles fine if you include `<cmath>` and remove the `Map` thing in the cpp file (since you haven't defined that in the header)

Comment: @Mat you are right, now it's compiling!! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

On the first look there are 2 possible reasons for this error:

The most obvious one:
Your class definition is incomplete, it should be

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    unsigned int x; 
    unsigned int y; 

    MyClass() { x = y = 0; }
    MyClass( unsigned int px, unsigned int py ) { x=px; y=py; }

    float Calculate( MyClass &myClass );
}; // semicolon

float MyClass::Calculate( MyClass &myClass )
{
     if(x<myClass.x)
             ....//treatment
}
```

Additionally, make sure your source file (*.cpp) includes your header file (*.h)

So both files would look like that:

```
// .h file
class MyClass
{
public:
    unsigned int x; 
    unsigned int y; 

    MyClass() { x = y = 0; }
    MyClass( unsigned int px, unsigned int py ) { x=px; y=py; }

    float Calculate( MyClass &myClass );
};

// .cpp file
#include "MyClass.h"
//definition of constructors
float MyClass::Calculate( MyClass &myClass )
{
   if(x<myClass.x)
             ....//treatment

}
```

Comment: I've edited my post and to add the real code and I've done both of these things.

Comment: @Anila Ive tested the code here and it works perfect. Note that you still havent posted the whole code, as what is the 'map' variable?